# Testing to see if one mean lies within a percent difference of another mean?

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, equivalence

**I am not looking for a complete solution, but just something to help me get started on the right track**.

Let's say that you have two samples from independent populations 1 (a control group) and 2 (a treatment group), both of size $n$. You get a sample from both populations and gather data from the samples.

However, from population 1, you have some prior data as to what the values of $\mu_1$ and $\sigma_1$ (the population S.D.) are. You want to find a test such that the treatment causes a $100p\%$ increase or decrease in the quantity of interest compared to the mean value of sample $1$ (or a more extreme increase/decrease), where $p \in (0, 1)$ is fixed. Given a minimum desired power and an $\alpha$ level, how do we find the ideal value of $n$?

My instinct is to use a two-tailed hypothesis test, but I'm not sure if I should treat it as a one-sample $t$-test (assuming $\mu_1$ is a fixed value) or a two-sample $t$-test (and I'm not sure how I would use $\mu_1$ in this case). Either way, there is an issue with the width of the interval not being fixed.

Comment: Are these percentages count proportions (counts divided by total counts)?

Comment: @Glen_b Not necessarily.

Comment: Okay, maybe I'm confused about what you're getting at. Are the observations percentages or does the mention of percentages only refer to the $p$ in your setup of the interval?

Comment: @Glen_b The mention of percentages only refers to $p$. To clarify the problem: I want to do a hypothesis test on two means. I get two samples $X_1$ and $X_2$. Say, for example, group 1 is a control group and group 2 is a treatment group. From population 1, I have some previous data as to what $\mu_1$ and $\sigma_1$ are. I want to find a test such that the treatment causes a $100p$% increase or decrease in the quantity of interest compared to the mean value of sample 1 (or a more extreme increase/decrease).

Comment: Yeah, I totally misunderstood, and I think the person answering did as well. Your title in particular is misleading, since it implies the data are percentages. Would you mind editing? I think it will greatly improve the chances of a useful answer.